# How get values from object in js?

Tags: javascript

I have object in JS:

```
File​
accepted: true​
dataURL: "data:image/jpeg;base64,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…"​
height: 3024​
lastModified: 1537604334019​
name: "%6qdJvzqS1OTnJATyo8lZQ.jpg"​
previewElement: <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-success dz-complete dz-image-preview">​
previewTemplate: <div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-success dz-complete dz-image-preview">​
processing: true​
size: 1636910​
status: "success"
type: "image/jpeg"​
upload: Object { uuid: "af40c7d8-7d46-49f3-8770-1d6998a8485f", progress: 100, total: 1637145, … }​
webkitRelativePath: ""​width: 4032​xhr: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 30000, withCredentials: false, … }​
<prototype>: FilePrototype { name: Getter, lastModified: Getter, webkitRelativePath: Getter, … } 
SystemConfiguration:642:17
```

How can I get accepted (true or false) and name?

Comment: it is a very basic javascript. how your object look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the name of the object is obj.
Then you refer to the attribute as

```
let val = obj.accepted;
```

Answer (score 0):

`var myFile = new File([""], "filename");`

Now you can access any properties of myFile in the following way.

`myFile.name;
myFile.accepted;`